# Is there a way to force blender dynamically calculate the (random values of) Geometry nodes for instances used in another geometry node modifier?

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

Currently just playing around to learn ins and outs of geometry nodes. I am trying to make a bush-like plant - that potentially could be used as a branch for a tree, and possibly the trees would be used as a forest scenery.
So I created branch object in geometry nodes, attaching instances of leaf objects to simple extruded plane functioning as a branch base.
Distribution, rotation and scale of the leaves is randomized via *Point distribute* and *Attribute randomize* nodes. Seed values for these are taken from *Random float* node in hopes of randomizing these for each instance.

Well... It seems to be not working - when I create Bush object and instance the branch objects to it via Geometry Nodes, all the branches have the same configuration of leaves. When I use *Object>Apply>Make instances real* , the branches all still remain similar, and, seem to refer to a single instance of geometry nodes modifier.

Is there a some kind of setting or way around it?
Is it possible at all ?
The result that I am looking for here is that all the branch instances would have differently transformed leaves, all the bushes would have differently transformed branch instances, etc.

Edit:
I am aware of possibility to create this kind of effect inside a single geometry nodes modifier, but stacking several separate ones would be more easily manageable...

Comment: this is a really good question. Unfortunately i have no idea how to do it. And i fear it is in the "nature" of instance - it is always the same.

Comment: It sounds like you were working on this with the 2.9x nodes. With the geometry nodes overhaul in 3.0, this might be easier to pull off?

Comment: No, unfortunately it is currently not possible. An instance is a linked copy of the original object and you only have influence on the transformation of the instance, but no longer on the variables used during the creation.